# Post a json with a base64 file > 20Mo with OKHttp : connection reset

Tags: spring-boot, okhttp

I'm actually implementing a client that call a webservice. We have the following basic test:

```
@Test
void convertAndSignWithStoredCertificateVeryVeryBigFile() {
    try {
        String source = "src/test/resources/source/verybigfile.pdf";
        String destination = "src/test/resources/destination/verybigfile.pdf";
        String url = "http://localhost:8081/pdfmanager-ws/v1/convert-and-sign/";

        PdfConvertAndSignRequest request = PdfConvertAndSignRequest.builder()
                .headerData(HeaderDataRequest.builder()
                        .service("MyApp")
                        .connectTimeout(600)
                        .readTimeout(600)
                        .writeTimeout(600)
                        .build())
                .data(Collections.singletonList(PdfConvertAndSignRequestData.builder()
                        .pdf(Utils.fileToBase64(source))
                        .build()))
                .build();

        PdfConvertAndSignResponse response = pdfManagerHttpClient.convertAndSign(request, certificateName, url);
        Utils.base64ToFile(response.getData().get(0).getPdf(), destination);
    } catch (PdfManagerHttpClientException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getErrorMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This method implements the object required to call the client app that calls the webservice. In the AppManager, I simply have the following :

```
public PdfConvertAndSignResponse convertAndSign(PdfConvertAndSignRequest request, String certificateName, String url) throws PdfManagerHttpClientException {
    clientBuilder(
            request.getHeaderData().getConnectTimeout(),
            request.getHeaderData().getReadTimeout(),
            request.getHeaderData().getWriteTimeout());
    try {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = MappersUtils.objectMapper();
        Request clientRequest = requestBuilder(
                url + certificateName,
                objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request));
        try (Response response = client.newCall(clientRequest).execute()) {
            checkResponseCode(response);
            return objectMapper.readValue(response.body().string(), PdfConvertAndSignResponse.class);
        }
    } catch (PdfManagerHttpClientException e) {
        throw new PdfManagerHttpClientException(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e.getErrorMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

In my MappersUtils class, I just implemented an object mapper :

```
public static ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z");
    objectMapper
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true)
            .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
            .setDateFormat(df)
            .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
            .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT);

    StreamReadConstraints streamReadConstraints = StreamReadConstraints
            .builder()
            .maxStringLength(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            .build();
    objectMapper.getFactory().setStreamReadConstraints(streamReadConstraints);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

THe method requestBuilder is simply building the request.

```
private Request requestBuilder(String url, String json) {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(json, MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"));
    return new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .build();
}
```

Finally, I do have the clientbuilder Where i set values for client and time outs:

```
private void clientBuilder(Integer connectTimeout, Integer readTimeout, Integer writeTimeout) {
    int timeOut = 60;
    this.client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(Objects.requireNonNullElse(connectTimeout, timeOut), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

My issue is that call works fine for small files, but for rather big files :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer

    at fr.dsidiff.pdf.client.PdfManagerHttpClient.convertAndSign(PdfManagerHttpClient.java:190)
    at fr.dsidiff.pdf.client.localhost.ClientPdfManagerApplicationConversionAndSignatureTest.convertAndSignWithStoredCertificateVeryBigFile(ClientPdfManagerApplicationConversionAndSignatureTest.java:104)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:420)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:826)
    at okio.OutputStreamSink.write(JvmOkio.kt:57)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$sink$1.write(AsyncTimeout.kt:99)
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.kt:255)
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.kt:146)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$KnownLengthSink.write(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:278)
    at okio.ForwardingSink.write(ForwardingSink.kt:29)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange$RequestBodySink.write(Exchange.kt:223)
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.kt:255)
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.kt:185)
    at okhttp3.internal._RequestBodyCommonKt$commonToRequestBody$1.writeTo(-RequestBodyCommon.kt:36)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:64)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:84)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:65)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:205)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:158)
    at fr.dsidiff.pdf.client.PdfManagerHttpClient.convertAndSign(PdfManagerHttpClient.java:183)
    ... 1 more
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Une connexion établie a été abandonnée par un logiciel de votre ordinateur hôte
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:325)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
        at okio.InputStreamSource.read(JvmOkio.kt:94)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:125)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.kt:427)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:320)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.HeadersReader.readLine(HeadersReader.kt:29)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:179)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:111)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:95)
        ... 13 more
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
        ... 27 more
        Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Une connexion établie a été abandonnée par un logiciel de votre ordinateur hôte
            at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:325)
            at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
            at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
            at okio.InputStreamSource.read(JvmOkio.kt:94)
            at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:125)
            at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.kt:427)
            at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:320)
            at okhttp3.internal.http1.HeadersReader.readLine(HeadersReader.kt:29)
            at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:179)
            at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:111)
            at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:95)
            ... 13 more


                .readTimeout(Objects.requireNonNullElse(readTimeout, timeOut), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(Objects.requireNonNullElse(writeTimeout, timeOut), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
    }
```